# Changing a Pivot Table Filter using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on an Excel worksheet which has over 20 Pivot Tables. They all work fine but when I want to update the week, I need to do this for all Pivot Tables. Therefore, I want to use VBA to update the filters with just a single button click. The week which should be selected is filled in a cell and from there the filters should be set. This is the code I have currently:

```
Sub Update_Week()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld As PivotField

Set Sheet = Worksheets("Leverancier")
Set PvtTbl = Sheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel19")
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("[Mutatiedatum].[Jaar-Week-Dag].[Weekjaar]")

Sheet.Range("D4") = PvtFld.DataRange

End Sub
```

In `PvtFld.DataRange`, the current value can be retrieved but `PvtFld.CurrentPage = Sheet.Range("D3")` which should set the value from D3 ("week 33, 2016") to the filter doesn't work.

The structure of the filter which I want to set is shown in picture below:

[image: Structure]
The part of setting is not shown in the code I currently have. Can someone help me with the above to solve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
temp = Sheet.Range("D3")
PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters
PvtTbl.PivotFields("[Mutatiedatum].[Jaar-Week-Dag].[Weekjaar]").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=temp
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It blocks at: "PvtFld.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="" & temp & ""

Comment: It is only marked yellow. How can I see the error? Good to learn that also to debug :-)

Comment: Sorry. (Translated from Dutch) It states: Error 1004 while executing. By the application or object defined error

Comment: Edit version error:
Error 1004 while executing: Feature PivotFields class PivotTable can not be retrieved

Comment: Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: i am not able to figure out why you are getting this error, as it works for me. could you tell me the exact name of the field you are filtering. is it `[Mutatiedatum].[Jaar-Week-Dag].[Weekjaar]` or just `Weekjaar`

Comment: I were also in doubt about that, so therefore I started to retrieve data from it instead of putting data into the filter. Weekjaar didn't work, only [Mutatiedatum].[Jaar-Week-Dag].[Weekjaar] worked for that.

Comment: My feeling tells me that it the type of input. Since "week 33, 2016" is a String and the filter will be a Date. It uses values from a different worksheet. I don't know if that can give any troubles.

Comment: What also might be valuable is that if I loop over the filter `[Mutatiedatum].[Jaar-Week-Dag].[Weekjaar]` there is no PivotItem